# Detecting any and all versions of Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10, conditional-comments

There used to be a nice way to tell if a web browser is IE or not, by using this technique in HTML:

```
<!--[if IE]>
Non-IE browsers ignore this
<![endif]-->
```

or

```
<!--[if !IE]-->
IE ignores this
<!--[endif]-->
```

but this [doesn't work anymore](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2011/07/06/html5-parsing-in-ie10.aspx?Redirected=true) in IE 10.

Any idea what to use instead to tell IE from other web browsers (using HTML or JavaScript)?

PS. I need to be able to tell **ANY version** of IE from non-IE web browser.

Comment: You shouldn't need to. IE10 is largely standards-compliant. Don't try write for a specific set of browsers, try to follow the standards and IE10 should hold up well.

Comment: @JamesAllardice: No, it's not.

Comment: 2 ways: feature detection ; or User Agent check

Comment: Plus, I'm not asking only about IE10. I'm asking about a solution for ALL IEs.

Comment: Rather than User Agent sniffing (which is horrible and evil and should be avoided wherever possible), you should use feature support detection: http://modernizr.com/

Comment: What is it specifically that you have problems with in IE?

Comment: @Guffa: You must be kidding me, right? The web is full of stuff like this: http://sixrevisions.com/web_design/why-ie9-is-a-web-designers-nightmare/

Comment: @c00000fd - The article you linked to is about IE9. Have a look on http://caniuse.com. IE10 offers vastly better support for modern technologies. Your conditional comments will work as they are in IE9.

Comment: @JamesAllardice: Guys, I don't care about IE10, IE9, IE11, IE15... I want to catch all of them. Is that possible? That's what I'm asking.

Comment: @c00000fd - Only with some form of user agent sniffing. But it would help if we understood *why* you need to do this. There may be a better option e.g. feature detection.

Comment: @JamesAllardice: OK. I just loaded up my site into IE10 and it still doesn't play some GIF animations from JQuery. For some stupid reason it just doesn't. I can make IE play them by reloading those GIFs, but I need to know that it's an IE since this hack is needed only for it. But again, this is too specific to explain here, and this is not what I'm asking for. I can fix it, if I know that it's an IE web browser.

Comment: @c00000fd: No, I'm not kidding. I want to know what specific problems *you* face, in order to help you. It's likely that you should detect a specific feature instead of detecting the browser, but that's hard to tell without knowing anything at all about what you are trying to do.

Comment: In all seriousness, IE10 really isn't that bad a browser (in fact, I gather that jQuery has more fixes for Chrome than for IE10). And plenty of other people are using animated GIFs with it and not having problems. Please, ask a separate question that explains the specific problem you're having; it's a near certainty that the SO collective will be able to help you fix it so it works perfectly well in all browsers without needing any browser-detection hacks.

Comment: As many of the others above have stated, rather than apply a blanket IE fix, it makes much more sense to use [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) to look for specific features that you are trying to use.

Answer (score 9):

I appreciate all your insight, but none of it answers my actual question. Again, I am not asking about the *feature detection*. All I need to know is if the web browser is IE or not. The following uses JavaScript and seems to work for all current versions of IE (including IE10):

```
<![if IE]>
<script type='text/javascript'>
if(/*@cc_on!@*/false)
var bIsIE = 1;
</script>
<![endif]>
```

and then to check if it's IE, do this from JavaScript:

```
if (typeof (bIsIE) != 'undefined')
{
    //The web browser is IE
}
else
{
    //The web browser is not IE
}
```

Obviously the code above assumes that the web browser has JavaScript enabled. But in my case the browser detection is relevant only if it has scripts enabled.

Comment: +1, because sometimes you just don't want to mess around with capability detection for deficient browsers. But aren't you missing some curly braces and an operator in that `if(/*@cc_on!@*/false)` block? Also, what is that block supposed to check?

Comment: Some features are not detectable.  I'm trying to detect IE because it doesn't support an `href` of `data:text/csv...`

Comment: Here's a problem with feature detection no one might mention:  In all versions of IE, you cannot use CORS with canvas toDataURL(), because it flags the canvas as dirty, even with CORS. Yet doing feature detection on CORS for IE9+ will come up as 'yes', it's just a quirk in how IE handles toDataUrl().

You can try{} catch {} the error, but don't bother, because IE won't "catch" the toDataUrl() call, it will break out of the try{} anyway as a security error. Better to just detect "is this IE?" before attempting the toDataUrl and use a local proxy for IE rather than disable CORS for sane browsers

Answer (score 5):

Every version of Internet Explorer is different from the others, just as every version of Chrome, Firefox, and Opera are different from their predecessors. You don't target vendors such as "Microsoft", "Google", or "Mozilla" when you develop websites—you target features.

Rather than asking "*I'd like to use ::after, is this browser a Microsoft browser?*" You should instead ask "*Does this browser support pseudo-elements on the :: prefix?*" This is feature-detection, and it's nearly always perfectly on target. Rather than guessing what a browser is capable of by its vendor, you determine what it's capable of by what it can actually do.

This may not be the answer you were looking for, but it's the correct answer nonetheless. If you're asking how to identify all Microsoft browsers, you are approaching the *problem* (or what you perceive to be a problem) incorrectly.

For proper solutions, I would encourage you to use tools like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) and [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com). These will handle API normalization, shimming of newer elements in older browsers, as well as feature-detection. This is the *correct* way to do things, and had developers been taking this approach from the beginning you may not have such a distaste for Internet Explorer today.

Answer (score 3):

The link you give in your question -  [doesn't work anymore](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2011/07/06/html5-parsing-in-ie10.aspx?Redirected=true) - which is to Windows Internet Explorer Engineering Team Blog  leads to the following statement

> Conditional Comments
>
> ```
> <!--[if IE]>
>
> This content is ignored in IE10 and other browsers.
>
> In older versions of IE it renders as part of the page.
>
> <![endif]-->
> ```
>
> This means conditional comments can still be used, but will only
>   target older versions of IE. If you need to distinguish between more
>   recent browsers, use [feature detection](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/04/14/same-markup-writing-cross-browser-code.aspx) instead.

It seems to me that the IE team are strongly pushing for the use of feature detection rather than browser detection as the quote from the feature detection link above shows.

> **Same Markup: Core Guidelines**
>
> ```
> **DO**
>     Feature Detection
>     Test whether a browser supports a feature before using it.
>     Behavior Detection
>     Test for known issues before applying a workaround. 
> **DON'T**
>     Detect Specific Browsers
>     Also known as browser detection. Don't use the identity of a browser (e.g. navigator.userAgent) to alter page behavior.
>     Assume Unrelated Features
>     Don't perform feature detection for one feature, and then proceed to use a different feature.
> ```

So it appears that the Windows Internet Explorer Engineering Team are setting IE up so that you will not be able to use browser detection for IE10 and above.

EDIT
I do not use IE10 but does

```
navigator.appName=='Microsoft Internet Explorer';
```

work in IE10?

Answer (score 0):

It isn't enough to just say IE10 is good enough and ignore the problem. It really depends on what you are trying to do. For most purposes feature detection would likely handle what you need. The far, far more complicated route is to start user agent detection by pulling in the user agent string from the HTTP request header. If you aren't careful with this you can go wrong pretty quickly.

To view your current user agent string in a browser JS console:

```
console.log(navigator.userAgent);
```

Here is a list of reported user agent strings across all kinds of browsers:

http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/browser_ids.htm

Note that all MS Explorer agent strings will contain "MSIE," but first you have to weed out browsers like Opera that will also include the "MSIE" string in some cases.

Answer (score -1):

This function returns `true` if the client browser is **Internet Explorer**, tested on versions **9-10-11**.

```
function isIE(v) {
    var ie;
    ie = RegExp('msie' + (!isNaN(v)?('\\s'+v):''), 'i').test(navigator.userAgent);
    if (!ie) { ie = !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv[ :]*11\./) }
    return ie;
}

// Example
var ie = isIE();
var ie9 = isIE(9);
var ie10 = isIE(10);
```

NOTE: the function is incomplete and won't allow for `isIE(11)`